# Android and GSon

Tags: android, gson

I am starting to look at google's Gson.  The following code errors as it is entered in that the Gson in the last line is not recognised.  The imports are ok so what am I missing?

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.*;

public class BuildJsonObject {
    Gson myGson = new Gson();
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error that you're receiving?  I don't see anything wrong with that.  The only thing that I see different in my code is that my import is:  import com.google.gson.Gson;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the GSON Jar to your build path?

Right Click (Project) -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Go To 'Libraries' Tab -> Click 'Add External JARs...' then select the GSON jar file?

[image]

Comment: Thanks.   I looked at your build path screen and then mine and realised I'd downloaded the 'stream' version of the jar.   All ok now.  But what is the difference ?

Comment: If I understand it right, the stream version is just a subset of the entire package that involves only interacting with the JSON response incrementally for really high performance processing, which for my case (and I assume yours), is too narrow a scope for just that package.